# Declare a function with symmetric arguments

Tags: function-construction

I have a package that contains a function `f[a_,b_,c_]` which is explicitly symmetric but *only* in its first two arguments. How do I make Mathematica simplify things such that

`(f[x,y,z] + f[y,x,z])//FullSimplify = 2f[x,y,z]`

Even better would be a general function to declare which arguments are symmetric and antisymmetric...

Note: the function is not defined to do anything with those arguments, i.e. in the package I've only defined it via a Format[f[a_,b_,c_]] :=...

Comment: `SetAttributes[f, Orderless]` and `f[x, y, z] + f[y, x, z]` ??

Comment: I am not sure if I understood but this might be a duplicate of [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/258766/86543)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One can use

```
f[x_,y_,z_]/;(Order[x,y]<0) := f[y,x,z];
```

Comment: Or `f[x_, y_, z_] /; ! OrderedQ[{x, y}] := f[y, x, z]`

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
f[OrderlessPatternSequence[x_, y_], z_] := {x, y, z}

f[x, y, z] + f[y, x, z]
```

> `{2 x, 2 y, 2 z}`

```
f[x, y, z] + f[y, z, x]
```

> `{x + y, y + z, x + z}`

Comment: @Akoben. Try the various results of `f[OrderlessPatternSequence[x_, y_], z_] := ff[x, y, z]` (with `ff` undefined). You will see that `f[x, y, z] + f[x, z, y]` becomes `ff[x, y, z] + ff[x, z, y]` but `f[x, y, z] + f[y, x, z]` becomes `2*ff[x, y, z]`.

Comment: @march Thanks for your kind explanation and elaboration.